# Mallet DMR negative propability for feature-based topic-distribution?

Tags: java, machine-learning, topic-modeling, mallet

I've created a DMR Topic model (via Java API) which calculates the topic distribution based on the publication-year of the documents.

The resulting distribution is a bit confusing, because there are a lot of **negative propabilities**. Sometimes all propabilities for a whole topic are negative values. See:

[image]

**Q1:** Why are there negative values? The lowest possible possibility for a topic distribution for a given feature should be at least 0,0 ... I guess?

Additional I build a LDA model where the ModelLogLikelihood seems to be surreal. I trained the model with nearly 4 million documents and 20 topics. Alpha =1.0 ; Beta = 0.01 ; # iterations 1000;

Results in Model-Log likelihood:
**-8.895651309362761E8**

**Q2:** Can this value be correct? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for using DMR! LDA assumes that the prior for the topic distribution for each document is a Dirichlet distribution. The parameters for a *K*-dimensional Dirichlet are *K* non-negative real numbers. DMR-LDA generates a document-specific prior based on the properties of a document.

Q1: These are not probabilities, they are regression coefficients. If you have a document with feature `2014`, the value for the Dirichlet parameter for topic 1 with the expression `exp(-4.5 + -0.25)`. This is the default parameter plus the offset for 2014, exponentiated to make it non-negative. These values are equivalent to about 0.01 for the default value with no additional features, and 0.008 (78%) for 2014.

Q2: This is a common confusion! The key is that this is a *log* probability. The log function crosses 0 at 1, since anything to the 0 is 1. The log of any value *less* than 1 is negative. Since all probabilities are less than or equal to one, all *log* probabilities are zero or negative. The other thing that often surprises people is how large the log probabilities are. Let's say you have a language model where each word token is independent, and the probability of a given word is usually around 1/1000. The log probability of one word is therefore around -7.0. The joint probability of a whole collection is the product of the token probabilities, so the log of that joint probability is the sum of -7. I'm guessing your collection has about 100M tokens?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! You helped me a lot. 

Yes, you're right - The total amount of tokens is **95366337**